# JS infinite scroll data list

Tags: javascript, infinite-scroll

I'm searching for a fine JS component (may be jQuery based - but not mandatory) for making a list of `div`s with content loaded from a REST datasource. Think something like twitter's timeline.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found a suitable plugin. jQuery based and loads JSON via AJAX.

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll